# java thread sync between multiple objects

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a multi-thread multi-object system in which I have a `manager` and multiple `workers`. I need to synchronize the `workers` with the `manager`, like this:

`manager` does sth, gives the order to the `workers`, and then let the `workers` run in parallel, independent of each other. When they finished this round, they must wait for the `manager` to give them the new task or order. The `manager` issues the new order only if all the `workers` have finished their previous job.

I need to implement it using threads to avoid busy-waiting. However the synchronization is confusing.

Any idea?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: I have many ideas; I can give you a daily rate. Otherwise, write some code and work out what issues you have; then post here for help. We're not a code writing service. Hint: look at [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider I certainly didn't/don't want code writing service. Just a hint. The CyclicBarrier solved the problem.

Comment: It would help if you would describe why the manager issues a new order only when all workers have finished their jobs.

Comment: @Sidias-Korrado workers are using shared resources. The resources should be released before assigning new order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @boristhespider suggested, I used CyclicBarrier for both `manager` and `workers`.

After each `worker` finishes its task, it calls `barrier.await()`. Then for the `manager`, I check if `barrier.getNumberWaiting()==NumWorkers`. If it's `true`, it updates the tasks of each `worker` and then calls `barrier.await()`.

Comment: How do you check `barrier.getNumberWaiting()` without busywaiting the manager?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** i missed a important part that says new tasks should arrive only when all have finished. Therefore using LinkedBlockingQueue is not the best solution. I recommend using the CyclicBarrier boris-the-spider has recomended.

You can use a [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html)

Set a fixed capacity.

The `manager` can [put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#put(E)) tasks, and the `workers` can use function [take](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take()) to wait.

Comment: Sort of: I suppose if you have `n` tasks and `n` workers - and tasks take _long enough_ to run -  then when you post the `n` tasks to the `BlockingQueue` that would have each worker take a task and process it. But it doesn't solve the problem of the master waiting for the workers. The OP is likely better off with the very simple [`ExecutorService.invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)).

Comment: The master can wait for the workers by looking at  `queue.size() >= n` and sleep-wait a bit. Or the workers could signal their status , there are many ways to do it.

Comment: That won't work, not unless the workers place something back into _another_ queue - so you'd need two queues. I'm not saying your method won't work, I'm just saying you're reinventing the wheel; and that is usually an extremely bad idea when it comes to concurrent code. The `ExecutorService` code is part of the JDK, so very well tested. And it does exactly what's needed...

Comment: I am curious why you think the `queue.size() >= n` solution would not work. The queue holds the waiting tasks ready for taking.

Comment: Which queue? The workitem queue would have a `size` of `n` at the start, then a size of `0` once all work is taken. It would continue to have a `size` of `0` unless items are place back into the queue. Further, your master thread would have to busywait to determine the size of the queue - which is terrible.

Comment: Do you consider this code a busy wait ?
`if (work_queue.size() >= n) Thread.sleep(100);`

Comment: Well, that's not busy waiting but it does cost you `100ms`. So it's probably very slow; although that obviously depends on how long the tasks are. Consider, tasks take `15ms` to run (a decent minimum for multithreading to be advantageous)  - with your code each iteration would take between `15ms` and `115ms`; that's up to **10 times** worse than using `invokeAll`.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much.

Comment: The LinkedBlockingQueue can have a limited capacity, that solves the manager wait.

Comment: How exactly? I would need at least some pseudocode to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain 2 Blocking queues
1. for Task 
2. for  free worker

Let worker notify manager via a callback, which add them to free worker queue

Inside manager thread you can check for workers available.

quick implementation

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ManagerWorker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        BlockingQueue<String> taskQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

        Manager m = new Manager(5, taskQueue);
        service.submit(m);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            service.submit(new Worker(m, taskQueue));
        }

    }
}

class Manager implements Runnable {

    int workerCount;
    BlockingQueue<Worker> workerqueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    BlockingQueue<String> taskQueue;

    public Manager(int workerCount, BlockingQueue<String> taskQueue) {
        this.workerCount = workerCount;
        this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
    }

    public void callBackForFreeNotification(Worker worker) {
        workerqueue.add(worker);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < workerCount) {
                    workerqueue.take();
                    i++;
                }

                System.out.println("Manager Worker available");

                // add task to task queue here
                for (int j = 0; j < workerCount; j++) {
                    taskQueue.add("task");
                }
                System.out.println("Manager task added");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

class Worker implements Runnable {

    private Manager manager;
    private BlockingQueue<String> taskQueue;

    public Worker(Manager manager, BlockingQueue<String> taskqueue) {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.taskQueue = taskqueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){


        try {

            System.out.println("Worker - i have no work");
            manager.callBackForFreeNotification(this);
            taskQueue.take();
            System.out.println("Worker working");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Worker Done with work");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

}
```